# Run application in Raspberry Pi with a web browser

Tags: web-services, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I would like to build an application Raspberry Pi for controlling a 20 Inch monitor it will display some images.

**Long story**

Each user have an account (Web based application) and he/she is logged into account and upload some images/videos into his account (Stored AWS S3 buckets).
Later he can connect his Device it includes **20 Inch monitor+Raspberry Pi** to this account.
Here the crucial part comes he can able to start some features on this monitor some of are

1.Set up an image slideshow in the monitor.

2.Can able to stop it.

3.Cache images for some times.

ie  he/she control the monitor with a browser.
 Currently  we have Raspberry Pi 3 with RASPBIAN os  and the user web application. 
Is it possible to do with Raspberry Pi??

Comment: Do you understand what a Raspberry Pi is? It's not magic, it's just a small computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming (and too broad for any other StackExchange site)

Comment: @MSalters updated my question with relevant informations